# Koolstop set compatible for folding bike?

Tags: brakes, folding-bicycle, compatibility

Is this [Koolstop Road Pad Holder and Brake Pad Set](https://shopping.howei.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=119&product_id=1010) compatible for folding bike ? My bike is  using Dahon Speed P8.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://dahon.com/mainnav/folding-bikes/single-view/bike/speed_p8-1.html your bike has direct pull (a.k.a V-brakes). Your brake shoes should have threaded studs with spherical washers. There isn't really a point in getting a set with a holder given how often brakes on a folder would have to be replaced and the price difference, but Kool Stop does make V brake refills and holders.

You need the Kool Stop Mountain (a.k.a bmx) threaded salmon's or threaded thinlines (http://www.koolstop.com/english/mountain_pad.html or http://www.koolstop.com/english/thinline.html). The ones you linked will not fit (they are for caliper brakes).

The threaded thinlines may be a better option since they give a bit more room (they're a bit thinner).

Since you asked this question, some help with installing the brake pads may be useful:
http://sheldonbrown.com/canti-direct.html 
http://sheldonbrown.com/rim-brakes.html
http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/linear-pull-brake-service-v-brake-type
(And the back of the package the brakes come from)